# Unexpected ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Android

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

My app is throwing an unexpected ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and doesn't even tell me the line number where the error is thrown. I tried to use Log to put messages to check where is code is broken and I found that the array size is 5 but the error says **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4**

I am opening camera using intent:

```
File file = createImageFile();
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        Uri uri;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(pdf_viewer.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        else
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And my onActivityResult code is:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            try {
                new addImageInBack().execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

This is an AsyncMethod in which my code brokes everytime:

```
Log.e("1 - imgRotComp", " OK ");

            ArrayList<String> img_paths = send_pdf_images;

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/CamScan/.tempFiles");
            if(!f.exists())
            {
                f.mkdirs();
            }

            Log.e("a", "OK" + img_paths.size());

            for(int i = 0 ; i < img_paths.size() ; i++)
            {

                Log.e("b", "OK "+img_paths.size());

                int orientation = 0;
                try
                {
                    Log.e("c", "OK");
                    ExifInterface oldExif = new ExifInterface(send_pdf_images.get(i));
                    orientation = oldExif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.e("d", "OK");
                File a_file = new File(img_paths.get(i));
                Bitmap a_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(a_file.getAbsolutePath());

                float a_op_width = a_bitmap.getWidth();
                float a_op_height = a_bitmap.getHeight();

                if (a_op_width < 1500 && orientation == 0)
                    continue;

                Log.e("e", "OK");

                if(orientation == 6 || orientation == 3 || orientation == 8)
                {
                    Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();

                    if (orientation == 6)
                        rotateMatrix.postRotate(90);
                    else if (orientation == 3)
                        rotateMatrix.postRotate(180);
                    else if (orientation == 8)
                        rotateMatrix.postRotate(270);

                    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(a_bitmap, 0, 0, a_bitmap.getWidth(), a_bitmap.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

                    try
                    {
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yy-H-m-s", Locale.getDefault());
                        String dateTime = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
                        dateTime = dateTime.replace("-", "");

                        File temp_file = new File(f.toString() + "/", dateTime + ".jpg");

                        temp_file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(temp_file);
                        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                        fo.close();

                        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(temp_file);
                        String realPath = getRealPathFromURI(uri);

                        Log.e("l1","OK");

                        send_pdf_images.remove(i);
                        send_pdf_images.add(i, realPath);

                        Log.e("l2","OK");

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
          }
```

The strange part is my code brokes everytime when I click 4th image before that it works perfectly fine. t brokes between line **Log.e("d", "OK");** and **Log.e("e", "OK");** (only during 4th image clcik).

This is my complete Log:

```
E/a: OK5
E/b: OK 5
E/c: OK
E/d: OK
E/b: OK 5
E/c: OK
E/d: OK
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.camscan, PID: 27178
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
        at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6917)
        at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1268)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2165)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:788)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2830)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2357)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1493)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7283)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27178 SIG: 9
Process 27178 terminated.
```

EDIT:
PDFViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.camscan;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PDFViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<String> pdf_images = new ArrayList<>();


    public PDFViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> pdf_images) {
        super(context, R.layout.pdf_image_view, pdf_images);
        this.pdf_images = pdf_images;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pdf_images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return pdf_images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pdf_image_view, parent, false);
            viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pdfiv);
            viewHolder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pdftv);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv.setTag(position);

        Glide.with(context).load(pdf_images.get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);

        viewHolder.tv.setText(""+(position + 1));
        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView iv_image;
        TextView tv;
    }

}
```

What might be the cause of this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try debug mode, manual stepping through code to at least know after which line it crashes to narrow it down.

Comment: @AkashRaghav it is crashing due to grid view problem. See my EDIT. This is what I found after running it again and again

Comment: can you post the grid view adapter/relevant code.

Comment: I did now. This seems to be working fine when it gets called first time on Activity onCreate where I have selected images from gallery. But when I click new image from camera to add a new image to grid view dynamically I am calling this same function from my Activity onResult and there it crashes

Comment: I got the solution @AkashRaghav. See my answer. Thank you for your time  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution! I was doing a very very silly mistake. Suppose I am having 4 images in my grid view, when I am clicking new image from camera and as I receive the clicked image in my onActivityResult, I should update my grid view with the new image i.e., I should again call:

```
adapter = new PDFViewAdapter(pdf_viewer.this, pdf_viewer.send_pdf_images);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and then I should call my AsyncMethod that I posted in my question (where the error was thrown). But I was calling the AsyncMethod without updating my adapter and I was again accessing grid view elements in my AsyncMethod. That's the reason it was showing same ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException again and again.

Thanks a lot @Akash Raghav and @julianpjp for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
 File a_file = new File(img_paths.get(i));
```

try to log the value of i and try i -1.
The error says that you want the fourth element of the Array but the array length is only 4:   0,1,2,3.

Comment: It won't work. If I put **i-1** it will definitely go out of bound as my starting i value is 0. It will become -1 by your update.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the grid view where I am inflating the captured images. I have set my grid view height and width in such a way that only 4 of its items are completely visible at a time. So when I click 5th image and as it tries to inflate it, it crashes. But if I manually scroll to bottom after clicking 4th image, it works perfectly fine. How can I rectify this.